# Facing problem with 'request.POST.get()' method it is not fetching the right data

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have just started learning Django.
But, I couldn't resolve one problem I am facing, any kind of help will be appreciated

here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def homeGrade(request):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        num = float(request.POST.get("marks")) # here
        print(num)
        if num >= 80:
            grade = "Grade A"
        elif num >=60:
            grade = "Grade B"
        else:
            grade = "Grade C"
        msg = "Your marks are " + str(num) + " and your grades are " + grade
        return render(request, 'findgrade/home.html', {"msg":msg})
    else:
        return render(request, 'findgrade/home.html', {})
```

And here is my template home.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Find Grade</title>
    <script>
        function validate()
        {
            var m = document.getElementById("marks");
            var e = document.getElementById("err");
            var a = document.getElementById("ans");
            if( m.value = "" | m.value < 0 | m.value > 100)
            {
                alert("Invalid Marks");
                e.style.visibility = "visible"; 
                m.value = "";
                m.focus();
                a.textContent = "";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h2> Find grade app </h2>
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
        {% csrf_token %}

            <input type="number" name="marks" placeholder="Enter the marks" id="marks">

            <label id="err" style="color:red; visibility: hidden"> Invalid Input </label>

            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="Find">

        </form>
        <h2 id="ans"> {{ msg }}</h2>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

for some reason, variable num in views.py is receiving value 0.0 no matter what has subitted in the form.

Comment: What value is posted if you remove the `onsubmit="return validate()"`

Comment: This line is incorrect: `if( m.value = "" | m.value < 0 | m.value > 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.POST.get("marks", "default")`

The second arguement, replaces the value if nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your javascript:

```
if( m.value = "" | m.value < 0 | m.value > 100)
```

This is *very* incorrect. Firstly `m.value = ""` this is an *assignment* and not an equality check (Which should be like `m.value == ""`). Next `|` is not the logical OR operator (`||`) it is the bitwise OR operator. This basically ends up assigning `m.value = false` which simply means that it's value ends up being `0`.

You want to change that line to the follows:

```
if( m.value == "" || m.value < 0 || m.value > 100)
```